# Store time from NSTimer for next view (HELP!)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I'm becomming desperate. I've got a NSTimer in my second ViewController.

```
-(IBAction)start {
    myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 
                                                target:self 
                                              selector:@selector(showActivity) 
                                              userInfo:nil 
                                               repeats:YES];
}

-(IBAction)stop {
    [myticker invalidate];
}

-(void)showActivity {
float currentTime = [time.text floatValue];
newTime = currentTime + 0.01;
time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", newTime];        
}
```

`newTime` ist an instance variable (float) and `time` is the label where the time is shown.

Before calling the third ViewController, I stored the time this:

```
-(IBAction)right {

[self stop];

ThirdViewController *screen = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
screen.timelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", newTime];
[self presentModalViewController:screen animated:YES];
[screen release];
}
```

I stopped the timer and gave the time to the instance variable `timelabel` (UILabel).
In the third ViewController I created the same NSTimer with the same methods.
But when I open the third View Controller the timer starts from 0 again.

What's wrong about my code?

---

My third ViewController:

```
-(IBAction)start {

    myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}


-(IBAction)stop {

    [myticker invalidate];

}

-(void)showActivity {

    float currentTime = [timelabel.text floatValue];
    float newTime = currentTime + 0.01;
    timelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", newTime];        
}
```

Comment: If you have problems in the third view controller, you need to post the code of the third view controller!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please move you third controller code to the question.

You are not retaining `myticker`. I'm surprised that it works at all.

It is a bad idea to store float data in text field. It would be better to use float property for that:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController
{
  float currentTime;
  ...
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) float currentTime;
...

@end

@implementation MyController

@syntesize currentTime;

-(IBAction)start {
    self.myticker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 
                                                target:self 
                                              selector:@selector(showActivity) 
                                              userInfo:nil 
                                               repeats:YES];
}

-(void)showActivity {
  currentTime += 0.01;
  time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", currentTime];        
}
...

@end
```

Comment: The reason why it worked without `retain` is that the run loop (to which `scheduledTimer...:` automatically adds the timer) retains it, see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-SW6 . I agree it's a bad practice to rely on this feature.